# Is it feasible to publish metrics for Reactor-Netty more on connections?

Tags: prometheus, metrics, dropwizard, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

In one of our spring-reactive projects, I exposed the default HTTP-Client metrices. This gives me some insider information about upstream. But, now I need a breakdown of the response time as we see in Postman. I would like to know if it is possible to expose it using the current implementation or through a third-party library.

Here I have attached a piece of code, through which I am exposing some WebClient attributes.

```java
            HttpClient client = HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider.builder("fixed")
                        .maxConnections(700)
                        .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofMillis(config.getPoolMaxIdleTime()))
                        .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofMillis(config.getPoolMaxLifeTime()))
                        .metrics(true) //metrices exposed here
                        .build())
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT, config.getSocketTimeout())
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, config.getConnectionTimeout())
                .doOnConnected(connection -> connection
                        .addHandler(new ReadTimeoutHandler(config.getReadTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                        .addHandler(new WriteTimeoutHandler(config.getWriteTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                );
```

This is how Postman breakdown response time in their tool.

[image]

Comment: https://alexot91.medium.com/spring-webflux-custom-web-client-metrics-416f6d377f07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You enabled the metrics only on the `Connection Pool` level, but what you need actually is all `HttpClient` metrics.

You can do it like this:

```
HttpClient.create(...)
          .metrics(true, ...)
```

Using the code above, you will be able to see metrics on the `Connection Pool` level, metrics related to request/response, memory metrics.
More about all of this can be found in the [Reference Documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_metrics_6).

**UPDATE**

Here is how your code should look like

```
            HttpClient client = HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider.builder("fixed")
                    .maxConnections(700)
                    .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofMillis(config.getPoolMaxIdleTime()))
                    .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofMillis(config.getPoolMaxLifeTime()))
                    .build())
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT, config.getSocketTimeout())
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, config.getConnectionTimeout())
            .doOnConnected(connection -> connection
                    .addHandler(new ReadTimeoutHandler(config.getReadTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                    .addHandler(new WriteTimeoutHandler(config.getWriteTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            )
            .metrics(true, s -> s);
```

Comment: I tried this way, .metrics(true, s-> s) and get the below exception,
"incompatible parameter types in lambda expression". I'm using dependencies,
io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.19

Comment: Trying to use this method,
final SPEC metrics(boolean metricsEnabled, Supplier<? extends ConnectionProvider.MeterRegistrar> registrar) { .. }

Comment: You should not apply `metrics` configuration on the level of `ConnectionProvider`, but on the level of `HttpClient`. See the example above, it is on the level of `HttpClient`. I updated my answer.